# How to handle React Forms components

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux

I'm trying to make a simple form but after 10 examples/tutorials I still not understand some aspects :)

Scenario:
I'm getting data with redux action/reducer so the model is coming in props.reduxResponse in this form:

```
reduxResponse: { 
    name: "123", 
    anotherField: "456"
}
```

the main component where I get data ( and I hope I can make the update call :) ):

```
class Service extends Component {

  state = {
    reduxResponse: {}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getService(this.props.match.params.id);
  }

  handleSubmit = service => { this.props.saveService(service) }

  render() {
    let { reduxResponse = {} } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Infos</h3>
        <ServiceBasicInfoForm 
          service = { reduxResponse }
          handleSubmit={(service) => this.handleSubmit(service)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  getService: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  saveService: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  reduxResponse: state.reduxResponse.payload
});
export default withRouter(
  connect(mapStateToProps, { getService, saveService })(Service)
);
```

and the form

```
class ServiceBasicInfoForm extends Component {
  state = {
    service: {
      name: "",
      anotherField: {},
    }
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    props.handleSubmit(service); 
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if(this.props.service != prevProps.service){
      this.setState({ service: this.props.service });
    }
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    event.persist();
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {

    let { service = {} } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <ValidatorForm
          ref="form"
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          onError={errors => null}
        >
          <Grid container spacing={6}>
            <Grid item md={4} spacing={6}>
              <TextValidator
                value={this.state.service.name}
                ..... other props
              />
            </Grid>

            ..... other fields

          </Grid>
        </ValidatorForm>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ServiceBasicInfoForm;
```

and I can't understand exactly how can I pass the props.reduxResponse from Service to ServiceBasicInfoForm, then edit those values, handle submit and how the returned values after submit will be updated in ServiceBasicInfoForm

This is a sample example because the Service will contain ~4 forms.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a number of issues with your code. I'll try to address all of them.
First of all, `mapStateToProps` maps the Redux state to the component props. You have put the mapped object `reduxResponse` in your component state. In your render, you're also overwriting the mapped prop by assigning in the value `{}`. When creating `ServiceBasicInfoForm`, your passing `service` as a prop, but as far as I can see this has not been defined anywhere. What is this supposed to be? If you want to pass `reduxResponse`, then just do that:

`<ServiceBasicInfoForm reduxResponse= {reduxResponse}/>`

This would then be accessible in ServiceBasicInfoForm with:

`const {reduxReponse} = this.props;`

As for 'editing' props - you should never do this. The internal state of a component should be kept its state, not its props. If you want ServiceBasicInfoForm to communicate back to Service at a certain point, let Service pass in a callback function has a prop to ServiceBasicInfoForm:

`<ServiceBasicInfoForm reduxResponse={reduxResponse} callback={data => this.handleCallbackData(data)}/>`

Now, if you need ServiceBasicInfoForm to be rendered differently based on whether a submit has been made, you could just put this in the local state of ServiceBasicInfoForm, and render the component based on its local state.

Since you're using redux, you may also consider skipping the passing of these props alltogether. Instead you can connect ServiceBasicInfoForm to the redux state and update this when data arrives (using mapDispatchToProps), and let the the outer Service component listen to the global state (using mapStateToProps).

Comment: thanks, meanwhile i fond the `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)` and I add the callback like your example and now seems to work fine ... but I think I'm missed something -> Since you're using redux, you may also consider skipping the passing of these props alltogether.

Comment: I updated the question but I'm feeling that it needs to be a little bit simple than this ...

Comment: and if I create the `const {reduxReponse} = this.props;` it doesn't update when the props are changing

Comment: _Since you're using redux, you may also consider skipping the passing of these props alltogether_


The whole point of redux is to have one global state. This eliminates the need of messy passing of values on and down multiple component hierarchies. So what I mean is, that instead of passing data and callback functions between parent/child, you could just have each of them reading/writing to the global state.

Comment: or it's a good idea to pass all props to the form component? like `<ServiceBasicInfoForm {...props} />`

Comment: ok, thanks, I will take a look at mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps

Comment: _and if I create the const {reduxReponse} = this.props; it doesn't update when the props are changing_. This doesn't sound right. A component will always rerender when its props change (unless you're overriding lifecycle methods)

Comment: _or it's a good idea to pass all props to the form component? like <ServiceBasicInfoForm {...props}_

No, you should only pass the props that the component actually needs. Passing all props results in unnecessary re-renders (again, a component re-renders every time a prop changes), which impacts performance.

Comment: Also, if you don't already have it, get the react and redux plugins for your browser, these really help a lot in understanding and viewing props, local state, and redux state.

Comment: great, thanks, but one more question :) I need to keep the `componentDidUpdate` to update the state after props are changed, right? or how can I update the state ( after I submit the form and data comes back in props.reduxResponse ) to state ( so I can edit again )?

Comment: Yes, you can use ComponentDidUpdate to update the state based on the props, but very often this is an indication that something has been made in a needlessly complex way. Typically this lifecycle method is used when a change to a prop requires new data to be fetched e.g. async from a server. Why do you need to copy a prop to the state? Why can't you just use the prop directly instead? Also, please consider accepting the answer to your original question.

Comment: `Why do you need to copy a prop to the state?Why can't you just use the prop directly instead?` If i'm not copying the props to state how can I edit the input value, save them and then update them according to server response?